# How to fix the case of the data to receive replace searches a string for a specified value(appleJam), or a regular expression

Tags: regex, replace

```
> Blockquote
my expected output is:
"hello Alex, aewgtfrgtr,
"hello Alexx, aewgtfrgtrr, 
"hello Alexxx, aewgtfrgtrrr,ewgtf, 
"Hello World,"
```

I pass template and data to a function,then use a matc`enter code here`h to find the searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.then use replace searches a string for a specified value(appleJam), or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

```js
function test(template, data) {

  var jam = template;
  let appleJam = jam.match(/{{.+?}}/g);//{{???}}array
  let peachJam = Object.values(data);

      let toast = jam.replace(appleJam, peachJam);
        console.log(toast);
        return toast;

} //function
    
    test("hello {{name}}, {{erio9tr8dhygtj9eryh}}", {
      name: "Alex",
      erio9tr8dhygtj9eryh: "aewgtfrgtr",
    }); // hello Alex, aewgtfrgtr
    
    test("hello {{rsgwrg}}, {{eabernab}}", {
      rsgwrg: "Alexx",
      eabernab: "aewgtfrgtrr",
    }); // hello Alex, aewgtfrgtr
    
    test("hello {{a4trjhtr}}, {{h5yj6t5n}} {{wegr}}", {
      a4trjhtr: "Alexxx",
      h5yj6t5n: "aewgtfrgtrrr",
      wegr: "ewgtf",
    }); // hello Alex, aewgtfrgtr ewgtf
    
    
    test("Hello{{item}}", {
      item: " World",
    }); // Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

The shown function replaces only the first match `appleJam[0]`. We can replace more matches if we iterate the `data`:

```
function test(template, data)
{
    for ([key, value] of Object.entries(data))
        template = template.replace("{{"+key+"}}", value)
    return template;
}
```

If a key can appear repeatedly, we use `replaceAll`.

Comment: Can you say more about that? I don't understand yet.

Comment: I probably can say more if you say what you mean by _that_ or what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: What is the use of "for" in this JavaScript?

Comment: Is it used "For Of Loop" in here?

Comment: The [`for (… of …)` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) here executes the `replace` statement for each `[key, value]` pair in `data`, e. g. with `data` = `{
      rsgwrg: "Alexx",
      eabernab: "aewgtfrgtrr",
    }` it executes `template = template.replace("{{rsgwrg}}", "Alexx")` and `template = template.replace("{{eabernab}}", "aewgtfrgtrr")`.